# Populate Nested List of Classes from single data table c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have 2 classes having the same table structure in DB

```
public class Student
{
   public int SId {get; set;}
   public string SName {get; set;}
   public List<StudentDetail> SDetail {get; set;}
}

public class StudentDetail
{
   public int StudentDetailId {get; set;}
   public int StudentId {get; set;}
   public int ExamId {get; set;}
   public string Department {get; set;}
   public string Address{get; set;}
}
```

The data is fetched from the SQL by joining both the tables using StudentId. Every StudentId can have multiple Student details.
Now I want to populate the data in the above 2 classes. I have written the following code. Since one id have multiple details that's why I have used group by.

```
    var list = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(x => new Student
                   {
                       SId = x.Field<int>("SId"),
                       SName = x.Field<string>("SName"),
                       SDetail = new List<StudentDetail>
                       {
                            new StudentDetail
                            {
                                StudentDetailId = x.Field<int> 
                                ("StudentDetailId"),
                                ExamId = x.Field<int>("ExamId"),
                                Department = x.Field<string>("Department") 
                            }
                       }.ToList()
                   }).GroupBy(x => x.SId).Select(x => 
                      x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

But e.g. for Id 1 if there are 2 details then Student Detail list should have 2 records. But this code is creating two Id records having one record in Student Detail each like below

```
        Id -> 1 -> SId -> 1
        Id -> 1 -> SId -> 2
```

The data should be created like below:

```
        Id -> 1 -> SId -> 1
                -> SId -> 2
```

Any help?

Comment: if you want a hierarchy why do you flatten the collection by using `FirstOrDefault`? remove that part and the collection will remain hierarchical.

Answer (score 3):

The `Select` method creates one `new Student` for each record. For the `SDetail` field you create a list containing exactly one `StudentDetail`. When you then group by the `SId` field each `Student` still contains only one `StudentDetail`.

The solution is to do the grouping first. You can then think of each group representing a single `Student` and the elements of each group representing a `StudentDetail`:

```
var list = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(rec => rec.Field<int>("SId"))
                    .Select(gr => new Student
                    {
                        SId = gr.Key,
                        SName = gr.First().Field<string>("SName"),
                        SDetail = gr.Select(detail => new StudentDetail
                        {
                            StudentDetailId = detail.Field<int>("StudentDetailId"),    
                            ExamId = detail.Field<int>("ExamId"),
                            Department = detail.Field<string>("Department")
                        }).ToList()
                     }).ToList();
```

There is another overload of the `GroupBy` method which combines `GroupBy` and `Select`:

```
var list = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(rec => rec.Field<int>("SId"),
                             (key, gr) => new Student
                             {
                                 SId = key,
                                 SName = gr.First().Field<string>("SName"),
                                 SDetail = gr.Select(detail => new StudentDetail
                                 {
                                     StudentDetailId = detail.Field<int>("StudentDetailId"),
                                     ExamId = detail.Field<int>("ExamId"),
                                     Department = detail.Field<string>("Department")
                                 }).ToList()
                              }).ToList();
```